# Enable HTTP TCP connection requests in Arch Linux for neo4j

Tags: linux, tcp, neo4j, iptables

My laptop is running a local neo4j server. I can use it with `localhost:7474` but when i try connecting it with `192.168.1.12:7474` it is unreacheable.

Turns out linux is blocking connections other than web server port 80. Because i can access my Apache server on 192.168.1.12/

I am trying to allow TCP connections on port 7474 by using

`iptables -A TCP -p tcp --dport 7474 -j ACCEPT`

but it gives a response as -
`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

How can i make other clients access neo4j server running at my laptop on port 7474. My laptop IP addr is 192.168.1.12.

Comment: did you uncomment the webserver address line in conf/neo4j-server.properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that it is blocking it. Probably your neo4j server is only running at 127.0.0.1. You can check this out with `netstat -nplt`: you will probably see something (the apache) listening on 0.0.0.0:80 or :::80 (e.g. catchall address) but on port 7474 you will probably only see 127.0.0.1:7474 or ::1:7474. If this is the case you need to reconfigure your neo4j server to listen not only on localhost (don't know how, checkout the documentation).

Comment: I edited the neo4j server-properties.conf file so that it listens to not only 127.0.0.1. But still it isn't working.

Comment: working urls are-

localhost:7474/
127.0.0.1:7474/
0.0.0.0:7474/

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I had uncommented the webserver address line but it still wasn't working.
So i reinstalled neo4j. That solved it. Weird but worked.